# How can I fix problem with WNetAddConnection2A on app.manifest with level="requireAdministrator"

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have issue with zMapDrive. when I added app.manifest with level requireAdministrator.

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Cause for adding `app.manifest` was that `SendKeys.SendWait` not worked correctly.

This is class for map.

```
public class NetworkDrive
    {
        #region API
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")] private static extern int WNetAddConnection2A(ref structNetResource pstNetRes, string psPassword, string psUsername, int piFlags);
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")] private static extern int WNetCancelConnection2A(string psName, int piFlags, int pfForce);
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")] private static extern int WNetConnectionDialog(int phWnd, int piType);
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")] private static extern int WNetDisconnectDialog(int phWnd, int piType);
        [DllImport("mpr.dll")] private static extern int WNetRestoreConnectionW(int phWnd, string psLocalDrive);
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct structNetResource
        {
            public int iScope;
            public int iType;
            public int iDisplayType;
            public int iUsage;
            public string sLocalName;
            public string sRemoteName;
            public string sComment;
            public string sProvider;
        }
        private const int RESOURCETYPE_DISK = 0x1;
        //Standard  
        private const int CONNECT_INTERACTIVE = 0x00000008;
        private const int CONNECT_PROMPT = 0x00000010;
        private const int CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE = 0x00000001;
        //IE4+
        private const int CONNECT_REDIRECT = 0x00000080;
        //NT5 only
        private const int CONNECT_COMMANDLINE = 0x00000800;
        private const int CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED = 0x00001000;
        #endregion
        #region Propertys and options
        private bool lf_SaveCredentials = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Option to save credentials are reconnection...
        /// </summary>
        public bool SaveCredentials
        {
            get { return (lf_SaveCredentials); }
            set { lf_SaveCredentials = value; }
        }
        private bool lf_Persistent = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Option to reconnect drive after log off / reboot ...
        /// </summary>
        public bool Persistent
        {
            get { return (lf_Persistent); }
            set { lf_Persistent = value; }
        }
        private bool lf_Force = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Option to force connection if drive is already mapped...
        /// or force disconnection if network path is not responding...
        /// </summary>
        public bool Force
        {
            get { return (lf_Force); }
            set { lf_Force = value; }
        }
        private bool ls_PromptForCredentials = false;
        /// <summary>
        /// Option to prompt for user credintals when mapping a drive
        /// </summary>
        public bool PromptForCredentials
        {
            get { return (ls_PromptForCredentials); }
            set { ls_PromptForCredentials = value; }
        }
        private string ls_Drive = "s:";
        /// <summary>
        /// Drive to be used in mapping / unmapping...
        /// </summary>
        public string LocalDrive
        {
            get { return (ls_Drive); }
            set
            {
                if (value.Length >= 1)
                {
                    ls_Drive = value.Substring(0, 1) + ":";
                }
                else
                {
                    ls_Drive = "";
                }
            }
        }
        private string ls_ShareName = "\\\\Computer\\C$";
        /// <summary>
        /// Share address to map drive to.
        /// </summary>
        public string ShareName
        {
            get { return (ls_ShareName); }
            set { ls_ShareName = value; }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Function mapping
        /// <summary>
        /// Map network drive
        /// </summary>
        public void MapDrive() { zMapDrive(null, null); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Map network drive (using supplied Password)
        /// </summary>
        public void MapDrive(string Password) { zMapDrive(null, Password); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Map network drive (using supplied Username and Password)
        /// </summary>
        public void MapDrive(string Username, string Password) { zMapDrive(Username, Password); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Unmap network drive
        /// </summary>
        public void UnMapDrive() { zUnMapDrive(this.lf_Force); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Check / restore persistent network drive
        /// </summary>
        public void RestoreDrives() { zRestoreDrive(); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Display windows dialog for mapping a network drive
        /// </summary>
        public void ShowConnectDialog(Form ParentForm) { zDisplayDialog(ParentForm, 1); }
        /// <summary>
        /// Display windows dialog for disconnecting a network drive
        /// </summary>
        public void ShowDisconnectDialog(Form ParentForm) { zDisplayDialog(ParentForm, 2); }
        #endregion
        #region Core functions
        // Map network drive
        private void zMapDrive(string psUsername, string psPassword)
        {
            //create struct data
            structNetResource stNetRes = new structNetResource();
            stNetRes.iScope = 2;
            stNetRes.iType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            stNetRes.iDisplayType = 3;
            stNetRes.iUsage = 1;
            stNetRes.sRemoteName = ls_ShareName;
            stNetRes.sLocalName = ls_Drive;
            //prepare params
            int iFlags = 0;
            if (lf_SaveCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED; }
            if (lf_Persistent) { iFlags += CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE; }
            if (ls_PromptForCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_INTERACTIVE + CONNECT_PROMPT; }
            if (psUsername == "") { psUsername = null; }
            if (psPassword == "") { psPassword = null; }
            //if force, unmap ready for new connection
            if (lf_Force) { try { zUnMapDrive(true); } catch { } }
            //call and return
            int i = WNetAddConnection2A(ref stNetRes, psPassword, psUsername, iFlags);
            if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
        }
        // Unmap network drive
        private void zUnMapDrive(bool pfForce)
        {
            //call unmap and return
            int iFlags = 0;
            if (lf_Persistent) { iFlags += CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE; }
            int i = WNetCancelConnection2A(ls_Drive, iFlags, Convert.ToInt32(pfForce));
            if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
        }
        // Check / Restore a network drive
        private void zRestoreDrive()
        {
            //call restore and return
            int i = WNetRestoreConnectionW(0, null);
            if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
        }
        // Display windows dialog
        private void zDisplayDialog(Form poParentForm, int piDialog)
        {
            int i = -1;
            int iHandle = 0;
            //get parent handle
            if (poParentForm != null)
            {
                iHandle = poParentForm.Handle.ToInt32();
            }
            //show dialog
            if (piDialog == 1)
            {
                i = WNetConnectionDialog(iHandle, RESOURCETYPE_DISK);
            }
            else if (piDialog == 2)
            {
                i = WNetDisconnectDialog(iHandle, RESOURCETYPE_DISK);
            }
            if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
            //set focus on parent form
            poParentForm.BringToFront();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I am using a method zMapdrive.

```
private void zMapDrive(string psUsername, string psPassword)
        {
            //create struct data
            structNetResource stNetRes = new structNetResource();
            stNetRes.iScope = 2;
            stNetRes.iType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
            stNetRes.iDisplayType = 3;
            stNetRes.iUsage = 1;
            stNetRes.sRemoteName = ls_ShareName;
            stNetRes.sLocalName = ls_Drive;
            //prepare params
            int iFlags = 0;
            if (lf_SaveCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_CMD_SAVECRED; }
            if (lf_Persistent) { iFlags += CONNECT_UPDATE_PROFILE; }
            if (ls_PromptForCredentials) { iFlags += CONNECT_INTERACTIVE + CONNECT_PROMPT; }
            if (psUsername == "") { psUsername = null; }
            if (psPassword == "") { psPassword = null; }
            //if force, unmap ready for new connection
            if (lf_Force) { try { zUnMapDrive(true); } catch { } }
            //call and return
            int i = WNetAddConnection2A(ref stNetRes, psPassword, psUsername, iFlags);
            if (i > 0) { throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(i); }
        }
```

Now to the problem, when `app.manifest` is `default` then I can do the mapping and it shows me in `NetWork locations`, but when `app.manifest` is set to `level = "requireAdministrator"` I can do the mapping but it doesn't show me in `NetWork locations` but I can access it if I use `find`.

In my case I really need to show the mappings in `NetWork locations`.

Help me please to understand where is the problem, or suggest me another solution for drive mapping.

app.manifest default

[image]

app.manifest level = "requireAdministrator"

[image]

Comment: It actually works fine, you just can't see it.  Drive mappings are a per-user setting.  So they are made for the elevated admin account, not for the logged-in account.  Nothing you can do about that, you'll have to make SendKeys work for the logged-in account.

Comment: Yes , you was right , problem was on user.